# Add validation for auto populated field in django admin based on some condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

There is one model form, in which there are various fields, so all fields are filled except name field(name field can be kept blank), once we can hit submit button that name field should be auto-populated based on following code, name field length is restricted to 100, so if it exceeds that length, it gives Internal Server Error, I want to handle that ISE, instead of ISE I want to raise error(BadRequest) based on if condition mentioned in the code, but I am not able to raise it.

Even I have tried with try Except, but not able to raise error, can not able to do with clean method because in this class where save_model method is defined at there NestedModelAdmin in inherited.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not obj.name:
        obj.name = '{}_{}'.format(
            obj.id,
            obj.model_name,
        )
    if len(obj.name) > 100:
        raise BadRequest('Name cannot be longer than 100 characters.')
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, for auto pouplated field we can not get that field in clean method, as we are concatenating two values in save_model method, so in save_model method you can get auto pouplated field value but you can not raise error.

So the solution is, in clean method only we have to concatenate that 2 values which you are doing in save_model method and add the validation for it, something like below

```
def clean(self):
   concatenated_string = '{}_{}'.format(
    field_id,
    name_id,
   )
   if len(concatenated_string) > 100:
      raise ValidationError('Name cannot be longer than 100 characters.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ValidationError instead of BadRequest.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not obj.name:
        obj.name = '{}_{}'.format(
            obj.id,
            obj.model_name,
        )
    if len(obj.name) > 100:
        raise ValidationError('Name cannot be longer than 100 characters.')
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```